# Multiple Images displaying last image with dynamically created canvas and assigning to images

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

```
function innerAjax(FILE_DIR,imgJPGList){
      var imgLength = imgJPGList.length;

      $("#imgID").empty();// This is a div
               if(imgLength!=0){
               img = [];
                for(i=0;i< imgLength;i++){
                // dir = FILE_DIR+"/"+imgJPGList[i];

                var canvasCreator = document.createElement("canvas");

                canvasCreator.id = imgJPGList[i].substr(0, imgJPGList[i].indexOf('.'));
                console.log("canvas id is---"+canvasCreator.id);

               var canvas = $(canvasCreator).get(0);

               var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

                img[i] = new Image();

                img[i].onload = function() {
                console.log("inside onload function");
                ctx.drawImage(img[i],0,0);
                }
                img[i].src = FILE_DIR+"/"+imgJPGList[i];
                canvas.width = img[i].width;
                canvas.height = img[i].height;

                $("#imgID").append(canvas);
                $("#imgID").append($("<br/>"));
                }
            }
            $(canvas).mouseover(function myDown(e)
            {
             console.log("mouseover-----");
            })
        }
```

I have multiple images in a single page i am trying to create a dynamic canvas and set image height and width to it so that i could do some annotation on images. But my last image is getting displayed every time or nothing is displayed. Anyhelp is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing an asynchronous operation inside a loop which rarely work as intended.

JavaScript is single-threaded which means the code inside the onload handler won't be called before the loop finish, hence `i` will always be the last image.

You should also move setting canvas size to inside the handler as images not fully loaded doesn't have a width/height (it works on your system only because the images are in the browser cache).

To fix the last image problem, use `this` inside the handler which will represent the image loaded at that point:

```
img[i] = new Image();
...

img[i].onload = function() {
  // at the time this gets called, the loop has finished

  // these need to be here as image won't have width/height until fully loaded
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;

  ctx.drawImage(this, 0,0);   // use this (= actual image loaded)
  // append canvas to DOM here etc....
}

img[i].src = FILE_DIR+"/"+imgJPGList[i];
```

Comment: Hi can you help me answer this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28932978/how-to-use-paperjs-on-dynamically-created-canvas?noredirect=1#comment46122009_28932978