# How to use Paper.js on dynamically created canvas?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, paperjs

I have multiple `canvas` images on my page and I am trying to get the canvas id using `Paper.js` after the `mousedown` event on a single image through `jQuery`. My image disappears after a mouse click and after running the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function () {

    $('#imgID').on('mousedown', function (e) { //imgID is my div

        if($.isNumeric(e.target.id)){

        console.log(e.target.id);

        var canvas = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
        paper.setup(canvas);
        var path = new paper.Path.Circle({
        center: event.downPoint,
        radius: (event.downPoint - event.point).length,

        strokeColor: 'red'
        });

        // Remove this path on the next drag event:
         path.removeOnDrag();

        }else {
        return;
        }

        var offset = $(this).offset();
        console.log(e.clientX - offset.left);
        console.log(e.clientY - offset.top);
    });
}
</script>
```

I should be able to draw circles like on the link below on multiple images on my website.

[Drawing jQuery shapes using canvas elements](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Draw-Shapes-with-Html5-Canvas-Element-drawingshapes/)

I cannot use `"script type="text/paperscript" canvas=''"` as my `canvas` are created dynamically through JavaScript. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: I think i cannot reproduce the issue in jsfiddle as my images are in my local filesystem and all my code is in Ajax... is there any other way ?

Comment: Can you post the resulting html, what ends up on the page after your ajax runs? You should be able to copy it from 'inspect element' in chrome

Comment: I pasted in this by saving my HTML code... http://ideone.com/jvhSA6

Comment: I think i should do something like this "https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/479" which says i should use raster of paperjs

Answer (score 0):

If your saying that the element with the id `imgID` is added dynamically, you'll need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) like `$(document).on('mousedown', '#imgID', function (e) { // your code here...});`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.onload = function () {

    $(document).on('mousedown', '#imgID', function (e) { //imgID is my div

        if($.isNumeric(e.target.id)){

        console.log(e.target.id);

        var canvas = document.getElementById(e.target.id);
        paper.setup(canvas);
        var path = new paper.Path.Circle({
        center: event.downPoint,
        radius: (event.downPoint - event.point).length,

        strokeColor: 'red'
        });

        // Remove this path on the next drag event:
         path.removeOnDrag();

        }else {
        return;
        }

        var offset = $(this).offset();
        console.log(e.clientX - offset.left);
        console.log(e.clientY - offset.top);
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi DelightedD0D. imgID is not added dynamically it's a div... canvas are added inside div.

Answer (score 0):

I think that I understand what your problem is.
It is not trivial to manage several Paper.js contexts in parallel, there are some tricks to know.
Here's a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/8unksbyz/) that should get you on the track to find a solution adapted to your specific need.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debug Paper.js</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/acorn"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
    <style>
        html,
        body {
            margin   : 0;
            overflow : hidden;
            height   : 100%;
        }

        main {
            display : flex;
            height  : 100vh;
        }

        canvas {
            flex   : 1;
            border : 1px solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<main>
    <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    <canvas id="canvas2"></canvas>
</main>
<script>
    // For each canvas...
    const canvasIds = ['canvas1', 'canvas2'];
    canvasIds.forEach((id) => {
        // ...instantiate a dedicated PaperScope.
        // It will handle all the drawings related to this specific canvas.
        const scope = new paper.PaperScope();
        scope.setup(document.getElementById(id));
        // On mouse down...
        scope.view.onMouseDown = (event) => {
            // ...draw a circle at the mouse position.
            new scope.Path.Circle({
                center: event.point,
                radius: 50,
                fillColor: 'orange',
                // Make sure to always specify the shape parent.
                // Otherwise it will be inserted into the last created scope. 
                parent: scope.project.activeLayer
            });
        };
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```